# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input?

Tags: angular

I have an angular project and I have the following error:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at Response.Body.json (http.js:1091)
        at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (home.component.ts:57)
        at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:243)
        at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:190)
        at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
        at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
        at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
        at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
        at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
```

in the chrome console.
(home.component.ts:57):

```
  getBooks() {
    const promise = this._homeService.getBooks();
    promise.subscribe(
      data => {
        var jsonObject = data.json();
        console.log(jsonObject);
        this.books = jsonObject;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

the line 57 is

> var jsonObject = data.json();

can anybody help me please..

Answer (score 1):

1. It's very confusing that you name your **observable** as `promise`.
2. I guess you don't need to `data.json()`, if you are using the HttpCientModule of Angular it is by default.

Comment: unfortunately, it was working very well ,suddenly stop work, Don't know what is the problem??

Comment: Can you share the response from the server? does it is a valid JSON? Maybe you broke something in your API endpoint?

Comment: do you know ?? it's was just a wrong password for sql server  hhhh.